# Error Building Ruby in Sublime Text Editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, sublimetext2

```
puts "Hello World!"
```

When I click CTRL+B (Tools->Build) I get the following error in the console

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory [cmd: 
>   [u'~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby',
>   u'/home/ubuntu/rails_projects/Ruby/c2f.rb']] [dir: 
>   /home/ubuntu/rails_projects/Ruby] [path:
>   /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games]
>   [Finished]

Below is the Ruby.sublime-build

```
{
    "cmd": ["~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

I'm running this in Ubuntu 12.04, Sublime Text 2.0.1

~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]

What am I missing? I also have Ruby Test set up and that's working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be the **~** in your Ruby command path.
It may not be very general, but try to change

```
"cmd": ["~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"]
```

with

```
"cmd": ["/home/your_username/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"]
```

Comment: Can you help me edit this option? I have similar problem, Sublime is using my system ruby, not RVM ruby and I don't know where to edit the command path