# Building Ruby from Sublime text 3

Tags: ruby, linux, sublimetext3

My OS: Linux mint.

I installed Ruby using RVM by following a guide from internet.
I can now run ruby from terminal.

```
ruby -v : ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

and

```
which ruby:/home/shabin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
```

After that installed sublime text 3. Now when i run a ruby build from sublime 3 (Using Ctrl-B), i get below error.

```
/bin/bash: ruby: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: ruby "/home/shabin/LRTHW/ex1.rb"]
[dir: /home/shabin/LRTHW]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin:/home/shabin/.rvm/bin]
```

I followed this question:

[Error Building Ruby in Sublime Text Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311502/error-building-ruby-in-sublime-text-editor)

and numerous other sites. By Ruby.sublime-build file is:

```
{
  "env":{
    "PATH":"/home/shabin/.rvm/bin:${PATH}"
  },
  "cmd": ["rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.ruby"
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct build system? "Tools > Build System > Ruby"